# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. Can't install 4.5, says it's already installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an error in my project that says `Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed`. When I go to my project properties, it says that it is set to use .NET 4.5. But when I go to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` or `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64` I do not see any folder that says `v4.5`. I only have folders that say

- v2.0.50727
- v3.0
- v3.5
- v4.030319

But when I go to the [Microsoft Download Site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30653) to download .NET 4.5, when I run the exe I get something that says

```
Your Installation Will Not Occur
Details

Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is already a part of this operating system.  You do not need to install the .NET Framework 4.5 redistributable.

Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4.5 has already been installed on this computer.
```

When I go to my installed programs and do a search for `4.5` this is what I see:

[image: Imgur]

I am very confused on what I should do to fix this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the .NET Framework 4.5 that is searched for. It's the data provider that can't be found. Install the data provider for the database you are using.